# I want to make a train dataset's list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have a dataset

```
  a       b         label 
  2    apple         4
  1    bin           5
```

I want to make the list like

```
[[apple,4], [bin,5]]
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()
` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,'apple',4],[1,'bin',5]], columns = ['a','b','label'])
np.stack((df.b, df.label), axis = 1)

#op
array([['apple', 4],
   ['bin', 5]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.drop('a', axis=1).values.tolist()
[['apple', 4], ['bin', 5]]
```